# Am I missing something here regarding async/await?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I'm trying to understand how async/await works, but I know I'm missing something here.  This is my current code, which is not creating the state variable testing.

**Updated**

```
try {
  const getUpdate = await axios.post(
    `http://domain/rating-engine/v1/rates/${carrier}?plan=${benefitQuery}`,
    obj,
    config,
  );
  this.setState({ testing: getUpdate });
} catch (err) {
  this.setState({ testing: err });
}
```

I've now re-written the above code and works as expected now.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: Maybe you should log the error and find out?

Comment: It seems likely that you're getting an error, step through the code and find out (or log it rather than throwing it away). Your use of `await` is correct, assuming all of this is in an `async` function. (If it weren't, you'd be getting a SyntaxError.)

Comment: Ah, ok, so it does work in the same fashion as a standard promise, just written a bit different.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, yes, I do have this in an async function, I just don't have the entire function written out, only the main portion.

Comment: @pingeyeg - In fact, `async` functions return promises, and `await` consumes thenables (promise-like things). They're defined and implemented in terms of Promises.

Comment: Sadly, since there are two answers, you can't delete your question. You can flag it and ask a mod to delete it, though, since it was just a typo-level thing. Happy coding!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I tried deleting, but said I cannot do that since there are answers.  However, I did update my question to provide the answer based on what you guys have said, so there is that.

Answer (score 0):

`await` only runs in `async` function

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
  const getUpdate = await axios.post(
    `http://domain/rating-engine/v1/rates/${carrier}?plan=${benefitQuery}`,
    obj,
    config,
  );
  this.setState({ testing: getUpdate });
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's great you want to help! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help]. I see someone's downvoted this answer. Don't let that bother you, but do think about why they may have done so. In this case, I think it's because there was no reason to believe that the OP's code wasn't in an `async` function (and it turns out they've now confirmed it was). It's better to wait until you have solid information to work with rather than jumping in with a speculation. Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
async function getAxiosPost(){
    try {
      const getUpdate = await axios.post(
        `http://domain/rating-engine/v1/rates/${carrier}?plan=${benefitQuery}`,
         obj,
         config,
      );
      this.setState({ testing: getUpdate });
    } catch (err) {}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help]. I see someone's downvoted this answer. Don't let that bother you, but do think about why they may have done so. In this case, I suspect 2 things are at work: 1. Code dumps are not *useful* answers, always say *what* you did, and *why*. 2. There was no reason to believe that the OP's code wasn't in an `async` function (and it turns out they've now confirmed it is). It's better to wait until you have solid info to work with rather than jumping in with speculation. Happy coding!